# Select everything from one table and some from anothe table on SQL joining on 2 variables

Tags: sql, postgresql, querying

I am having a tough time selecting data from two tables.
I tried using every join but cannot figure it out.
I am using Postgresql

These are my tables:
Table_a

```
date, class, count_of_a
4/1/2015, B, 888
4/2/2015, A, 533
4/2/2015, A, 432
4/3/2015, C, 484
```

Table_b

```
date, class, count_of_b
4/2/2015, B, 345
4/3/2015, D, 553
4/3/2015, C, 334
```

I want this as my result:

```
date, class, count_of_a, count_of_b
4/2/2015, B,    , 345
4/3/2015, D,    , 553
4/1/2015, B, 888,
4/2/2015, A, 533,
4/2/2015, A, 432,
4/3/2015, C, 484, 334
```

Comment: Hint: full outer join.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with either a `full outer join` or `union all` and `group by`:

```
select date, class, sum(count_of_a) as count_of_a, sum(count_of_b) as count_of_b
from ((select date, class, count_of_a, NULL as count_of_b
       from table_a
      ) union all
      (select date, class, NULL as count_of_a, count_of_b
       from table_b
      )
     ) ab
group by date, class;
```

This method has a couple of advantages over `full outer join` (apart from not needed a bunch of `coalesce()` statements in the `from`).  Primarily, it is more general, so it will work when `date` and/or `class` take on `NULL` values.  Also, it will add the values correctly when there are multiple values for a class/date combination.